# TYPO3 ext:form multisite multilingual, like to have the site name in the subject line

Tags: forms, yaml, typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

I have a **form** defined with **yaml**, and use that trough the plugin **in six different sites** in a **multisite** ... to handle receipt well would I need to have the **site** from which the form originates **in the subject line** ...

is there a way to do that without overriding the finisher setting for each plugin ?
*(the sites are also multilingual, so that's not an option)*

**TYPO3 V10.4.37** (for the moment, I guess a possible solution would hold also in V11)